# Searching in xml with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to searching in a xml file. this is my linq sentece.

```
string _sSemptom  = "try";
XElement xe =  from c in xdSemptom.Elements().Elements().Elements()
                         .Elements().Attributes("Isim")
               where c.Value.Length >= _sSemptom.Length &&
                     c.Value.Contains(_sSemptom)
               select c.Parent
```

I can find the XElement that way, but if _sSemptom is "Try" I can't find it. How can I search using upper and lower case variations?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Actually, it turns out there isn't a [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) overload for [Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx). You can use [IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) instead:

```
c.Value.IndexOf(_sSemptom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
```